# Convert unsigned char the way printf does in C++

Tags: c++, hex, printf

I have an `unsigned char` that I want to convert to hexadecimal. I know `printf("%02X", char)` gives me the output I want, but it is sent to the terminal and is thus of little use. How can I convert the character to hexadecimal and store it in a variable the same way printf does it?

Comment: Um, use `sprintf` instead of `printf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sprintf` instead into a buffer, for example

```
char str[50];
sprintf(str, "%X02", char);
```

Comment: @mamills - of course, I was just showing an example. As Mooing Duck says, you should use `snprintf` to stop buffer overflows.

Comment: @mamills - 50 characters, as in the example, will always be large enough for that `sprintf` call. Don't replace simple code with complicated code out of fear of the unknown.

Comment: Thank you! This was a great and simple solution that did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int) x;

cout << ss.str() << endl;
```

You might want to tweak the `stringstream` some more though.

Comment: If `x` has type `unsigned char`, this will not work.  You have to explicitly convert `x` to `int` (or some other non-character type).

Comment: The way I'd do this is `ss << HexFmt(2) << (unsigned int)x;`.  A simple, user defined manipulator (which restores the streams formatting state at the end of the full expression).  I think the manipulators in the standard should be thought of more as examples; at least in application code, it's generally far better to define your own.

Comment: @JamesKanze Given my limited C++ knowledge, I didn't even think of a user-defined manipulator :-)

Comment: That's the next step.  You've got the right basic idea (although in an actual application, it's very unfriendly to leave `hex` set---the next bit of code which outputs an integer will be very surprised).  The next step is to "coalesce" frequently used formats into a single user defined manipulator, so you don't have to constantly repeat the same thing all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the fastest one?

```
struct hex_uchar {
   hex_uchar(unsigned char c)
   {
      value[0] = hc[c >> 4];
      value[1] = hc[c & 0xF];
      value[2] = '\0';
   }
   char value[3];
   static char hc[16];
};
char hex_uchar::hc[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
                           'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }; 


int main() {
   std::cout << hex_uchar('A').value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention: you are not converting it to hex value, you are converting to a null terminated string. Store it in a variable of your model is kind of nonsense.

Comment: He's formatting using `"%02X"`.  This means that he must pass an `int` or an `unsigned` or the behavior is undefined, and that the value will be interpreted as an unsigned.  Integral promotion means that any `char` type will be converted to `int`.  Where do you see any hint of a null terminated string in his code?